# Boostrap Dropdown Menu in Kendo Grid cell template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, kendo-ui

We have a web application using bootstrap and kendo ui (jquery) and in one of my pages, it contains a kendo grid with some columns and a bunch of options columns. I need to add more two options and we are losing space for it on the kendo grid. I was thinking to add a dropdown menu on the kendo column using the `template` options and add the html for dropdonw menu over there. I have tried it with this:

```
{
   template: '<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="\\#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="\\#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="\\#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
              </div>'
}
```

(Just break lines for easy reading).

The problem is when I run this, it works but the menu opens inside the cell and not over the cell. The user will not be able to click on these options. How can I get it working? Maybe adding a css class for this?

I have tried to add a div around the content in the template with `position: absolute` and `z-index:9999` but it did not worked!

You can see the problem in this kendo dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/EBOSEsub

Comment: The `z-index` solution won't work unless you position your parent elements as well [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.k-master-row td {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

It's also possible for `overflow` to be `initial` or `inherit`.

Comment: Thank you @jpllosa, it worked as expected. See the results here: https://dojo.telerik.com/EBOSEsub/11

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using the following css solution, unless there are other elements you plan on using inside the table.

```css
.k-master-row td {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[image: Desired result]

Comment: It didn't work, I tried to add your suggestion on the Dojo, but I got the same problem, take a look on it: https://dojo.telerik.com/EBOSEsub/7 , if you change it, give me the link. Thank you!

Comment: The link you just shared works perfectly for me @FelipeOriani